# Swap themes locally

Tags: plugins, theme-options, local-installation

I have a problem where my 'add new plugin' button doesn't work and it also doesn't appear on the normal menu.

I searched online and the solution that is being suggested is swap theme to check if the theme is conflicting or disabling some of the wp-core.

I have this site already in production and I would love to change it locally to another theme just for the sake of testing.

How can I do that? I try to avoid publishing a staging environment since it's a quite time consuming and I only need to debug this one problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the theme by going to Appearance. Then select twenty seventeen and check if all works. You can easily switch back to your original theme, not while happen.